# How do we handle duplicate questions from the site-merge?

Tags: discussion, beta, duplicates

Now that the Android questions from gadgets.StackExchange have been merged in, we've got a lot of duplicated questions that pre-date the start of beta.

Answers can be different, or come from the same people.

If one of us asked a question or gave an answer in gadgets.SE, that shows up on our profile here, but we don't get any credit for it [how would you give credit to a non-beta member, anyway?]

BUT, if we close questions from AE in favor of pre-existing gadgets questions -- what would happen to rep?

Comment: man, somebody done harshed on my original tags. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The questions should be merged, this will solve any rep problems when a global recalc is done

Answer (score 0):

As far as rep goes, StackExchange sites periodically get global recalculations, so I'm sure the rep for imported questions will be doled out accordingly when the next one happens here.

I'm not sure what to do with dupes, especially when both have an accepted answer.  So far I've just let them be (sometimes adding a cross-link in the comments), since both were the "first" to ask the question on their respective sites.